# Checkbox to look like expander

Tags: c#, wpf

I"m trying to make a `checkbox` / `button` type thing that looks exactly like the expander button.  I've written my code for `IsChecked`, but was hoping not to use the `checkbox`.  I'm not sure if this makes any sense... how to do that in xaml?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make a `CheckBox` look like an `Expander` is to modify the `ControlTemplate` of the `CheckBox` (I assume you're already trying this).

Therefore I would have a look at the `ControlTemplate` of the `Expander` and try to modify it to use the data of the `CheckBox` class (or maybe an approach in the over direction would be easier, you will have to find out).

To see, how the `ControlTemplate` of the `Expander` is defined you can use Expression Blend to extract the template or have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I should probably add that I'm at about a grade 5 level when it comes to this stuff... I'm trying to throw something together (I'm not much of a programmer...) so admittedly, I have no idea how to modify a control template :)